# No option anymore to install Vuesax via the Nuxt CLI?

Tags: nuxt.js

No option to install Vuesax framework in laravel-Nuxt project.
Last node v installed in me pc, I used npm init nuxt-app ,
and also try yarn! [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuesax was updated last time on the October 2, 2020, so it's pretty much abandoned at this point.
Hence why it was removed from the Nuxt CLI from [v3.7.0](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/releases/tag/v3.7.0).

Personally, I do not recommend try to force to use this framework here.
Neither I do recommend using Vuesax at all actually, there are far better frameworks out there, that are kept maintained, are versatile and as beautiful.

Comment: I did like the Card component! especially in Vuesax v4, And yes there are many framework out there but most of them kind of stiff. hope vuesax back to growing someday.