# Nuxt Error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') default.vue and index.vue not rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuesax

I'm using `nuxt.js` and `vuesax` as an UI framework, I did **modify** my `default.vue` in `/layouts` with a basic navbar template exemple from `vuesax`.
Then I **used** `@nuxtjs/router-extras` to **rename** my `"/"` and redirect it to `/login`, I also **used** a `vuesax` input type template in my `index.vue` to see if I could **render** my `/login` page (navbar + input) but it is showing be this error:

```
client.js?06a0:103 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at VueComponent.handleScroll (vuesax.js?574d:24324:1)
at VueComponent.mounted (vuesax.js?574d:24382:1)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863:1)
at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4235:1)
at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3158:1)
at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6390:1)
at Vue.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6609:1)
at Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3960:1)
at Vue.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4075:1)
at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4495:1)
```

[image]

again **I'm very new**, heres some code:

`default.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="center examplex">
    <vs-navbar target-scroll="#padding-scroll-content" padding-scroll center-collapsed v-model="active">
      <template #left>
        <img src="" alt="">
      </template>
      <vs-navbar-item :active="active === 'wallet'" id="wallet">
        Wallet
      </vs-navbar-item>
      <vs-navbar-item :active="active === 'profil'" id="profil">
        Profil
      </vs-navbar-item>
      <template #right>
        <vs-button>Login</vs-button>
      </template>
    </vs-navbar>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'

import 'vuesax/dist/vuesax.css' //Vuesax styles
Vue.use(Vuesax, {
// options here
})
export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  data:() => ({
    active: 'wallet'
  })
}
</script>
```

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="center content-inputs">
    hello
    <vs-input
      type="password"
      v-model="value"
      label-placeholder="Password"
      :progress="getProgress"
      :visiblePassword="hasVisiblePassword"
      icon-after
      click-icon="hasVisiblePassword = !hasVisiblePassword">
      <template #icon>
        <i v-if="!hasVisiblePassword" class='bx bx-show-alt'></i>
        <i v-else class='bx bx-hide'></i>
      </template>
      <template v-if="getProgress >= 100" #message-success>
        Secure password
      </template>
    </vs-input>
  </div>
</template>

<router>
{
"path": "/login"
}
</router>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'

import 'vuesax/dist/vuesax.css' //Vuesax styles
Vue.use(Vuesax, {
// options here
})

export default {
  data:() => ({
    layout: 'default',
    value: '',
    hasVisiblePassword: false
  }),
  computed: {
    getProgress() {
      let progress = 0

      // at least one number

      if (/\d/.test(this.value)) {
        progress += 20
      }

      // at least one capital letter

      if (/(.*[A-Z].*)/.test(this.value)) {
        progress += 20
      }

      // at menons a lowercase

      if (/(.*[a-z].*)/.test(this.value)) {
        progress += 20
      }

      // more than 5 digits

      if (this.value.length >= 6) {
        progress += 20
      }

      // at least one special character

      if (/[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(this.value)) {
        progress += 20
      }

      return progress
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`middleware/redirect.js`

```js
export default function(req, res, next) {
  const redirects = [
    {
      from: "/",
      to: "/login"
    }
  ]
  const redirect = redirects.find((r) => r.from === req.url)
  if (redirect) {
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: redirect.to })
    res.end()
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vuesax is not really maintained anymore](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax), latest commit being from 20th September 2020.

Hence why it's not part of the [Nuxt CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70530589/8816585) anymore.

If you're new, I recommend starting by using something more simple, well supported and maintained like Vuetify, Buefy, Tailwind or at least any other one available in the list.

[image]

Even starting directly with Nuxt without any prior Vue knowledge is quite risky.

---

Back to the topic, even if we fix the issues regarding a specific install issue here, we will probably face some others down the road. And since the project is not maintained anymore, it's pretty sure that at some point we will see a blocker of some sort.

Don't expect Vuesax to work with the new Nuxt3 at all for example. So yeah, sorry it's not an answer to your question but I feel like it's better if I tell you that now that later (after days of debugging).

---

PS: you're trying to use `res.writeHead` in a **client-side** middleware (`redirect.js`). If you want a redirect, you'll need to use more of a `$router.push` here to use the [Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/).

Comment: I appreciate your honesty there, thank you for taking your time to respond to me over all. I might try to work without any vue.js component and maybe extract vuesax front css because i rly like it and deal with with jquery and javascript I guess ! feels bad tho, vuesax could have been a wonderfull vue framework. just and edit: but seems like they have a totaly diffrent git for vuesax 4 with updates since october 2020 here https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax-next

Comment: The new project [looks abandoned](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax-next/issues/169#issuecomment-854380750) there too, and it's not active commit-wise for almost 2 years. Abandoning a project twice is a heavy red flag for me personally. You could totally replicate the CSS of Vuesax by yourself but you will spend quite a lot of time on it. I'd recommend rather using something [Bulma-based](https://buefy.org/), [DaisyUI](https://daisyui.com/) or anything really, from here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#responsive While paying attention to support + popularity to not have the same issue.

Comment: What do you love that much in Vuesax? Using jQuery in 2022 is something that I really do not recommend, especially when Vue is lighter than this library and that nowadays we have super clean and nice features baked directly into modern JS (ESNext). I'll recommend properly learning Vue, getting used to writing simple CSS, then upgrading to a UI framework (if needed), then taking the Nuxt path. Basics are important IMO. @HDS_frenchguy

Comment: Im actualy very good at css and jquery ! but it's just a matter of speed I think, but I do hear you ! learning vue.js as we speak, about nuxt.js: I think i'm rushing to learn vue and hoping nuxt gets along while working on it, that's true ! maybe i should learn about nuxt before I guess. Thank you so much for DaisyUI, I never knew it existed ! even tho I checked the awesome vue list last week, hard to check them all x)

Comment: @HDS_frenchguy it's nice if you have great CSS basics. Regarding jQuery, I'd say that you can forget everything about it, because there is no real reason to use jQuery in state-based modern framework, I'd even say that it's deprecated (I do tell so to anybody posting question here at least). Yeah, don't forget that Nuxt is something on top of Vue, don't rush things otherwise you will have more issues debugging. Yeah, there are quite a lot actually (I've recommended DaisyUI but it's based on Tailwind, not sure if you're familiar with it). Not sure if my answer answers your question btw.

Comment: wonderfull, thank you so much for taking your time and energy ! I took note of everything 